# Award a bounty for a specific answer

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

OK, here's the thing :

- I posted a question on Stack Overflow around 1 hour ago ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451492/optimization-needed-algorithm-implementation-takes-up-too-much-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451492/optimization-needed-algorithm-implementation-takes-up-too-much-memory/14451571#14451571))
- I've obviously started no bounty, related to this question

Now, what I want to do :

- Award some extra points to the author of the answer (there is already a correct answer), purely out of respect for his effort and his immense help.

How could I do this?

Comment: Accept and upvote it. And wait for two days to add a bounty.

Comment: @hims056 I've already done that. Just want to see if there is any other way than waiting for 2 days...

Comment: No there is no way to do so.

Comment: @hims056 Hmm... OK, so it is, then. Thanks for the input! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to award extra reputation to the author of the answer except bounty. You can accept and upvote the answer (which you did great!). You can wait for two day to add bounty.

Answer (score 4):

You wait two days, add a bounty, then award it to the helpful answerer.

Answer (score 0):

well you can first accept answer and up vote it and if you really want to give prize to OP of answer than you can set bounty after tow days also so supports this

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164567/187824)?